# Issues on install package control on sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I installed sublime text 3 and i need to install package control ..so when i refer [**this**](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) page.

I just confused, what should i follow,

Can anyone help me to guide this docs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to copy the given code in the sublime text 3 console. (Show Console in the view menu)

It will download and install the package control. (You should see notifications in the console)

Once installed, you'll have access to the package control commands in the command prompt. (You can access it by pressing `ctrl` + `shift`+ `p`)

Answer (score 0):

In build 3126 (released Sept. '16) a menu item (and command palette entry) was introduced to easily install *Package Control*.

It can be found under `tools -> Install Package Control` or by looking up *Package Control* in the command menu (`ctrl/cmd` + `shift` + `p`).